# python websockets, multiple requests, why only requests are received?

Tags: python, websocket

I am trying to test out if I send out multiple requests at the same moment using coroutine can cause the server side receives corrupted data.

My test is based on the sample code from: https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html

Somehow, for the following code, the server side only receive one requests? Anyone has some insights? thx

server (this is basically the same code from the websockets Getting Started webpage):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                                                                                                                                         
                                                                        
# WS server example                                                     
                                                                        
import asyncio                                                          
import websockets                                                       
                                                                        
async def hello(websocket, path):                                       
    name = await websocket.recv()                                       
    print(f"< {name}")                                                  
                                                                        
    greeting = f"Hello {name}!"                                         
                                                                        
    await websocket.send(greeting)                                      
    print(f"> {greeting}")                                              
                                                                        
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)               
                                                                        
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)               
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Client, I created 1000 tasks, and schedule to run them as soon as possible:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3                                                  
                                                                        
# WS client example                                                     
                                                                        
import asyncio                                                          
import websockets                                                       
                                                                        
uri = "ws://localhost:8765"                                             
connection = None                                                       
async def hello():                                                      
    global connection                                                   
    name = "What's your name? "                                         
                                                                        
    await connection.send(name)                                         
    print(f"> {name}")                                                  
                                                                        
async def main():                                                       
    global connection                                                   
    connection = await websockets.connect(uri)                          
                                                                        
#asyncio.run(main())                                                    
if __name__ == "__main__":                                              
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()                                     
    loop.run_until_complete(main())                                     
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(                               
        [hello() for i in range(1000)], return_when=asyncio.ALL_COMPLETED
    ))
```

**UPDATE**
The solution is to use a loop.

Comment: If you have a solution, you can post it below and accept your own answer!

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason: the server side, handler should use a loop so that the corroutine will not finish immediately after received the first request.

Comment: Ahh sorry didn't see your answer before I posted mine. Glad you fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation you linked also includes this paragraph just below the server code:

> On the server side, websockets executes the handler coroutine hello once for each WebSocket connection. It closes the connection when the handler coroutine returns.

The client code you linked creates one connection and sends messages on that connection. After the client sends the first message, the server closes the connection, so the next 999 messages you attempt to send are being sent on a closed connection.

If you update the `hello` handler to include a loop, you will see all messages.

```
import asyncio                                                          
import websockets                                                       
                                                                        
async def hello(websocket, path):
    while True:
        name = await websocket.recv()                                       
        print(f"< {name}")                                                  
                                                                        
        greeting = f"Hello {name}!"                                         
                                                                        
        await websocket.send(greeting)                                      
        print(f"> {greeting}")                                              
                                                                        
start_server = websockets.serve(hello, "localhost", 8765)               
                                                                        
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)               
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: you are right, I need to have a while loop inside hello coroutine. thx